# Why was Blockchain.info DecryptWallet removed?

Tags: blockchain.info

https://blockchain.info/DecryptWallet.html has been removed for quite some time. Anyone know why?

PS. FWIW, an archived copy at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/r2vFpz4e)

Comment: Your URL is bogus, did you mean https://blockchain.info/DecryptWallet.html ?

Comment: Fixed URL Above

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=594570.0 for ways to export your blockchain.info wallet to another client.

As for the why, at this point I would say it has to be bad organization or possibly lack of funding. Blockchain.info has been fundamentally broken for quite some time (a quick search yields a post on bitcointalk over a year old for a still unresolved, somewhat minor problem: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=271633.0 and if you do a bit of digging you can find plenty more)

Comment: How does/did this differ from the import wallet option once logged in? Source code here: http://pastebin.com/r2vFpz4e Is it because of security concerns? Also, given the source code, does the html still decrypt a wallet? I've had no luck, perhaps it's relying on server side JavaScript?

Comment: Another option for exporting keys out of a bc.i wallet and into another is here: https://github.com/prof7bit/wallet-key-tool. Note however that it appears this tool doesn't support the full breadth of bc.i wallet formats: it supports version 2 wallets and only the most recent iteration (out of three) of version 1 wallets.