# Decipher xprv or seed from keystore when I know the password

Tags: seed

I know http://iancoleman.io/ but it does not help me as this is the other way around.

I have dump with: `keystore`: `xprv` and `seed`. I want to decipher `xprv` or `seed` because I know the password, but I have no tool to do that.

How can I do that?

EDIT: This is a `.json` file.

Comment: What software was used to encrypt the xprv and seed? Was it a known version of a specific wallet application?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I don't know that. I have `.json` file.

Comment: Could be a blockchain.info wallet? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/35914/13866

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick rather not.